# Facebook marketing API - fetching ad keyword stats

Tags: facebook-ads-api

I want to fetch ad keyword stats using Facebook marketing API, I found some documentation regarding the same in the Facebook developers section & here is the link for the same.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-keyword-stats

In order to get ad keyword stats for a particular account do I need to loop through all accounts, campaigns & ads or is there any direct way where I can pass ad account & get all ad keyword stats?

Please help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I worked with and finally fixed it all but, it pulls insights like CPC, impressions, etc. and based on the params you use you can get it from account, campaign, adset, and even ad levels. So let me know if this can help you out.

```
<?php

        require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
        use FacebookAds\Api;
        use FacebookAds\Object\AdUser;
        use Facebook\Facebook;
        use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
        use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Campaign;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdsInsightsFields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Ad;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdSetFields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\AdCampaign;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdFields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdImageFields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;
        use FacebookAds\Object\AdSet;
        use FacebookAds\Object\AdCreative;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdCreativeFields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdCreativePhotoDataFields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\AdCreativeLinkData;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdCreativeLinkDataFields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\CampaignFields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Page;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdPreviewFields;
        use FacebookAds\Object\Values\AdPreviewAdFormatValues;
        use FacebookAds\Object\AdVideo;
        ?>

Here is the general code I am trying

<?php
        // Init PHP Sessions
        session_start();

        $fb = new Facebook([
          'app_id' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
          'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
        ]);

        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

        if (!isset($_SESSION['enter api key here'])) {
          $_SESSION['enter api key here'] = null;
        }

        if (!$_SESSION['enter api key here']) {
          $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
          try {
            $_SESSION['enter api key here'] = (string) $helper->getAccessToken();
          } catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
            // When Graph returns an error
            echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
          } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
            // When validation fails or other local issues
            echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
          }
        }

        if ($_SESSION['enter api key here']) {
          //echo "You are logged in!";

        // Initialize a new Session and instantiate an API object
        Api::init(
          'xxxxxxxxx', // App ID
          'xxxxxxxxx', //app_secret
          $_SESSION['enter api key here'] // Your user access token
        );

    ?>
<div id="fbdata"></div> <?php

    $account = new AdAccount('act_xxxxxxxxxx');


        $params = array(

        'date_preset'=> 'last_28d',


            'thumbnail_width' => 200,
            'thumbnail_height' => 150,
            'level' => 'campaign',
            'limit' => '15'

        );

$fields = array(
  AdsInsightsFields::CAMPAIGN_NAME,
  AdsInsightsFields::CAMPAIGN_ID,
  AdsInsightsFields::IMPRESSIONS,
  AdsInsightsFields::CLICKS,
  AdsInsightsFields::REACH,
  AdsInsightsFields::SPEND,
  AdsInsightsFields::CPM,
  AdsInsightsFields::CPC,
  AdsInsightsFields::ACTIONS, 
);

$field = array(
  AdCreativeFields::TITLE,
  AdCreativeFields::THUMBNAIL_URL,
  AdCreativeFields::BODY,
  );

            $params1 = array(
          'time_range' => array(
            'since' => (new \DateTime($beginDate))->format('Y-m-d'),
            'until' => (new \DateTime($lastDate))->format('Y-m-d'),
          ),
            'thumbnail_width' => 200,
            'thumbnail_height' => 150,
            'level' => 'ad',
            'limit' => '5'
        );      

$adcreatives = $account->getAdCreatives($field, $params1);
?>      
        <table class="fbtable">
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Ad Image</th>
                <th>Ad Body</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
foreach($adcreatives as $t2){

        echo"<tr>
        <td>$t2->title</td>
      <td><img src='$t2->thumbnail_url'/></td>
      <td>$t2->body</td>
    </tr>";
}

        $insights = $account->getInsights($fields, $params);?>

        <table class="fbtable">
            <tr>
                <th>Campaign ID</th>
                <th>Campaign Name</th>
                <th>Impressions</th>
                <th>Clicks</th>
                <th>Reach</th>
                <th>Spend</th>
                <th>Total Actions</th>
                <th>CPM</th>
                <th>CPC</th>
            </tr>

            <?php

foreach($insights as $i) {
    $impress = number_format((float)$i->impressions);
    $reach = number_format((float)$i->reach);
    $totalAction = number_format((float)$i->actions);
    $cpc = number_format($i->cpc, 2, '.', '');
    $cpm = number_format($i->cpm, 2, '.', '');
    echo"<tr class='fbtable'>
      <td>$i->campaign_id</td>
      <td>$i->campaign_name</td>
      <td>$impress</td>
      <td>$i->clicks</td>
      <td>$reach</td>
      <td>$$i->spend</td>
      <td>$totalAction</td>
      <td>$$cpm</td>
      <td>$$cpc</td>
    </tr>";
}
        }else {
          $permissions = ['ads_management'];
          $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://where you want login to be.com', $permissions);
          echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook</a>';
        } 


?>
```

Comment: That code seems to be completely unrelated to the keywordstats API @Genext was asking about (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-keyword-stats/).